# Kendo datepicker select today onward only

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this date range in [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/iqoSolOf), but I want date from only can select today and onward only.
Meaning I cannot select date previous than today.

> dateFrom >= today and dateUntil >= dateFrom

[FULL DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/iqoSolOf)

Comment: Why don't you use https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/daterangepicker/index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [min](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/configuration/min) property of datepicker which will set the minimal date range. Updated dojo is [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/@paulrajj/AqEKUdAf).